# file copy error from system to cifs mount

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, mount, cifs, cp

When coping a file greater than 64kB from an Ubuntu server to a CIFS mounted windows share, most of the data is copied, but it seems the last chunk doesn't get copied.  The size doesn't match, and the md5 check sums don't match.  I have plenty of file space, but then I use cp, I get the following...

```
cp: closing `cloudBackup/asdf.txt': No space left on device
```

Using rsync, I get the following...

```
rsync: close failed on "/home/fluffy/cloudBackup/.asdf.txt.qrBWe6": No space left on device (28)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(752) [receiver=3.0.8]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (29 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(601) [sender=3.0.8]
```

I have full read/write permissions on the mounted share.  I can copy via SSH just fine.  Any ideas?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but your problem seems similar to this bug report: [cifs: i/o error on copying file > 102336 bytes](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=773705)

Maybe you can try with the work around suggested there.  Simply put:

```
wsize=98304
```

along the options of your cifs mount.